# How can I parse the response of axios to an attribute in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So,
I have an axios call to an api which I am able to console out however I need to parse the result into an attribute of a React component but all I get is that it is undefined

my code is as follows and I am sorry for the dodgy code I am just trying to get it to work... somehow

```js
useEffect(() => {
    loadTableData();
  }, []);


  const loadTableData = () => {
   
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`)
      .then(res => {
        const { data } = res;
      
        settableData({ ...tableData, data });
  
      })
      .catch(err => {
        
        if (err.response.status === 401) {
          toast.error(`You do not have permission to view this resource`);
        }
          if (err.response.status === 404) {
          toast.error(`The resource cannot be found`);
        }

      });
     
    };
```

```js
 <Table data={data} />
```

I get an error saying `data` is not defined even when I try to output only one element like `{data[0].title}`

how can I get hold of `data` and send it to the `data=`  attribute of `<Table`

If there is a better way than how I planed to do it, I appreciate all suggestions

Thanks in advance

Comment: This could be totally wrong but it could be the fact that your calling data before its actually finished processing the data, when i do stuff like this i will usually add some sort of loading state and wrap it around the component im passing into so it will only call that component once the axios data has returned, this may not be your case but cant tell without more code

Answer (score 1):

Try the simplest solution

```
{data && <Table data={data} />}
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve that all I get is `Line 192:14:  'data' is not defined`  no-undef

Comment: Or the best if you will share whole component

Comment: line 192 is `{data && <Table data={data} />} `

Comment: Wait then the problem is with the wrong variable name. Can you share the whole component?